# Accessing Devops Azure Pipeline Artifacts from from Azure Function

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, cicd, azureportal

I am creating a CI/CD pipeline for my Azure Resources using ARM Template.
In my Arm Template I am using *zipdeploy* to deploy the code of my azure function.

```
"resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
              "type": "extensions",
              "name": "zipdeploy",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "packageUri": "[parameters('packageUri')]"
              }
            }
          ]
```

Basically, I need to specify the packageUri, it needs to be accessed over the internet.

In my Azure Pipeline I am creating a zip package of my function and publishing to Azure pipeline artifacts using *dotnet publish*
and then I am getting the URL: https://dev.azure.com/ifolor/_apis/resources/Containers/$(Build.ContainerId)/drop?itemPath=drop/myfunction.zip

task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

Problem:

This URL is private, the Azure function cannot access this artifact

Is it possible to give access permissions to my Azure function from Azure Portal to access the pipeline artifacts from Azure Pipeline?

Pipeline artifact:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> *Is it possible to give access permissions to my Azure function from Azure Portal to access the pipeline artifacts from Azure Pipeline?*

No.

Typically, you don't use an ARM template to deploy your application, you use a continuous delivery pipeline that pushes the changes out to the site, as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cyaml).

i.e.

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<Azure service connection>'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    appName: '<Name of web app>'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```